# My web-app is not showing after firebase deploy, how can i solve this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-hosting

I have tried to clear cache, and tried other solutions from stackoverflow but it is still not working.

I did run build and used my dist folder when deployed. The deploy is successful but i can't see any content.

Im using react, typescript & vite.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your Firebase project structure and the content of the `firebase.json`file?

Comment: It is working now. I have refreshed the page like 20 times. Then waited 5 minutes and the content have shown up.

Comment: {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}